# Add Custom Field on Odoo General Ledger Report

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have tried to add Custom field called x_gstn in Odoo General Ledger Report But It Shows the Following Error

```
    Odoo Server Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 315, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, values, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_579_43993
  File "<template>", line 3, in body_call_content_43992
  File "<template>", line 8, in body_call_content_43991
  File "<template>", line 59, in foreach_43990
  File "<template>", line 77, in foreach_43989
KeyError: 'x_gstn'

Error to render compiling AST
KeyError: 'x_gstn'
Template: 579
Path: /templates/t/t/t[4]/div/table/tbody/t/tr[2]/td[4]/span
Node: <span t-esc="line['x_gstn']"/>
```

So I Don't How to Rectify it

Kindly Share your Ideas with me...

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Kindly See the Code in the following link [link](https://files.fm/u/4z33ee44#/view/code.txt)